# interactive matplotlib over ssh crashing, Anaconda Scientific Python Distribution

Tags: python, ssh, matplotlib, anaconda

I've installed Anaconda on a remote Mac OS 10.8.5 machine, and I'm trying to forward matplotlib graphics back to my local machine, but IPython keeps trying to use the remote machine's native graphics and crashing.  Has anyone else experienced this?  I can do this with the old Enthought Python Distribution (EPD), so I know the machines involved are set up for it.

I've asked this question [elsewhere](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/_F9UgtiyH0k), but without luck. Thanks for any help.

```
localmachine:~ me$ ssh -Y remotemachine
Password:
Last login: Fri Sep 12 10:46:08 2014 from localmachine

remotemachine:~ me$ ipython
Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (x86_64)| (default, Aug 21 2014, 15:21:46) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import matplotlib

In [2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [3]: plt.rcParams['backend']
Out[3]: 'TkAgg'

In [4]: matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

In [5]: plt.plot([1,2],[3,4])
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
CGColor with 0 components
/Users/me/anaconda/bin/python.app: line 3: 80244 Abort trap: 6           /Users/me/anaconda/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"
```

Comment: Does it work if you use a different backend?

Comment: No, both TkAgg and Qt4Agg do the same thing.

Comment: Found something from a recent Anaconda [changelog](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/changelog.html) : "on MacOSX, Tk in now linked to Cocoa (instead of X11)" . To anyone using Anaconda across a network, this is not an "enhancement."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting at Anaconda 2.0, Continuum [stopped linking tk with X11](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/changelog.html#id2) and instead linked to Cocoa, which makes attempting to forwarding network graphics crash the interpreter.  Network forwarding of interactive matplotlib using the TkAgg backend works again when I downgrade tk to the last version that linked to X11:

```
conda install tk=8.5.13
```

The drawback is that now I can no longer upgrade/install anything that tries to update tk.  Also, the Qt4Agg interactive backend still crashes the interpreter.  It's a step forward, I guess.

*Edit*: I see that you can pin packages at a certain version, described [here](http://continuum.io/blog/advanced-conda-part-1).

Comment: I tried you solution (downgrading tk to 8.5.13 and setting the backend to TkAgg but it still gives the same error. And I couldn't find an even older tk than 8.5.13.